# Syntax for displaying (embedding) an image in html with the image path being dynamic and stored in a DB field

Tags: html

I have a list on my site that displays info about companies and includes their logo. If hard coded (all cmopanies would get the same logo) like this it works fine:

```
 <img src="logos/company1Logo.jpg">
```

The logo path on my server is stored in a database field for each company. My program returns the field as {logo}, which in the above example would be - logos/company1logo.jpg - in the logo database field for company 1.

I have tried the following and none work.

```
<img src = "{logo}">

<img src = &quot;{logo}&quot;>

<src = <q>{logo}<q>>
```

I have made it work by constructing the entire line in MYSQL with

```
concat('<img src=','"',{logo},'"',' ','height=','"','35px','"','>')' AS logo2,
```

but getting all the spaces and quotation marks correct when there are many attributes is time consuming and I have to repeat this for several fields including complex video embeds.

Any suggestions for constructing the simple src attribute in html using a database field?

To answer the question, The the Working concat is placed with a simple: (Note: I also edited the Concat expression above to show it named `AS logo2`.

```
<div >
        {logo2}
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description on how the value in the MySQL database does get added to your HTML code. Add all the source code necessary to show how your system works.

Answer (score 2):

You have typo - change `scr` to `src`

```html
<img src="logos/company1Logo.jpg">
```